# How to match features in new records for NLP BOW

Tags: nlp, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a dataset that has 100,000 records

data in this dataset are 2 columns
1- Text
2- Class

When I apply BOW of my model I get big list of features

That is fine, I managed to work with them

my problem is after building the model and deploying.

now if a new text came with new words then the model wont work as it wokds in same feature structure

Example
"This is a test, test is important" , Red
"Adam pass a test", Green

so my final dataset is

```
This is a test important Adam pass class
 1    2 1 2    1          0    0   Red
 0    0 1 1    0          1    1   Green
```

once model created and got this text

"test and exam are similar", Yellow

in this case the set of features has new features which are

and exam are similar

the model will break coz these features never included in the training model

I wonder how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If there is new data with labels, you have to retrain the existing model to learn the new relationships.